# How can we use Typescript with CodeceptJS for testing framework?

Tags: typescript, codeceptjs

I have to create a testing framework using CodeceptJS. I am trying to use typescript instead of javascript to write my page objects and tests. Can someone help with what configuration is required in conf.js or steps.ts file

I have added below in conf file but not sure what else to add
  require: ["ts-node/register", "should"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add package `ts-node` to your package.json dev dependencies. And install dependencies
2. Add `require: ["ts-node/register"]` to config.
3. Make sure, your `tests` regexp in configuration supports `ts` files:
   for example `tests: "./tests/*.spec.ts"`

Definitions for codeceptjs are generated by command `codeceptjs def`.
https://codecept.io/commands#typescript-definitions

You should add this definitions in your tsconfig.

**P.S.**
There are an example for TS&CodeceptJS integration:
https://github.com/elukoyanov/codecept-typescript-example

Pay attention, it has one tsconfig for main project (in project directory) and second tsconfig for codeceptjs only (in `src/specs/e2e` path)

Comment: Hi Evgeny, Thanks for the help. However i could see below error and in the sample shared i see this has been removed. I honestly don't know what this is for (looks like for test events like start etc). Dont we need this

steps.d.ts:77:15 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventEmitter'.
77   dispatcher: EventEmitter

Comment: I see it was added 3 weeks ago.
It was later, than repo created.  https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/pull/1800/files#diff-b38e49bd02b239814a0c2fa24175ecd4R87

I\ll try to search solution

Comment: Try to manually change `EventEmitter` on `NodeJS.EventEmitter`.
I'll make a fix for one of the next releases.

Comment: Thanks alot Evgeny

Comment: Codeceptjs 2.3.0, released today, includes this fix

Comment: Hi Lukoyanov, i just updated the codeceptjs to 2.3.0 but tsc -w still gives the same error. Is there something i am missing

Comment: What about Gherkin? It doesn't seem to support typescript. only JS

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [TypeScript example from the CodeceptJS developers on Github](https://github.com/codeceptjs/typescript-boilerplate).

The official documentation also has [step-by-step instructions for configuring TypeScript support](https://codecept.io/typescript/).